# Pass URL Parameters to Public Lightning Community

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to convert a public (no-login) sites page to a public (no-login) Lightning Community with a context-sensitive LWC in it (requiring parameters).

One of the nice things about public sites pages is you could pass URL parameters like this in a link that you provide (for example) in an email:

**[site URL]?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3.**

The parameters above are available to your apex/visualforce code.

Is there a way to do this with a public Lightning Community that contains an LWC that needs the passed in parameters?  It seems like the parameters are wiped out whenever I click on a community link where I am trying to pass parameters.....

(I **was** able to pass GET/URL parameters to a public REST API community.  That works fine as the parameters are available in the REST request object.)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: if I summarize, ur que is how to open a lwc/aura comp as url as we can do with VF page. so its not possible in community. you will have to use create a new community page then drag lwc there. add logic to get params from page url.

Comment: I am not sure about this part _It seems like the parameters are wiped out whenever I click on a community link where I am trying to pass parameters_. If I go here, the parameters are still available: https://mstools.force.com/s?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3

Comment: Ayub you are onto something good!  I created an additional page for my public community and when the URL is for that page the URL parameters are NOT wiped out when you click on the link (to the secondary page).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Creating a secondary page for the community and passing URL parameters to the secondary page worked!